# Why am I getting weird result using parseInt in node.js? (different result from chrome js console)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, parseint

I just noticed that:

```
//IN CHROME JS CONSOLE
parseInt("03010123"); //prints: 3010123

//IN NODE.JS
parseInt("03010123"); //prints: 790611
```

Since both are based on V8, why same operation yielding different results???

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1645

Comment: What version of Node? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @RenatoGama: Works fine in 0.10.4.

Comment: This is why `parseInt()` should always be used with a radix. (I can reproduce it with 0.8.18.)

Comment: @Juhana what is radix?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: @Juhana your link actually answers my question, thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Undefined behavior occurs when the string being passed to [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) has a leading 0, and you leave off the radix parameter.

> An integer that represents the radix of the above mentioned string. Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified.

Some browsers default to base 8, and some to base 10.  I'm not sure what the docs say about Node, but clearly it's assuming base 8, since `3010123` in base 8 is `790611` in base 10.

You'll want to use:

```
parseInt("03010123", 10);
```

Comment: thats it! thanks. you may want to improve your answer by adding this link as reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: you can also use Number() as alternative.

Comment: Node 6.6: `parseInt("03010123");` -> 3010123