# `if` statement comparing return value of `prompt` to number is never executed

Tags: javascript, if-statement, prompt

I am writing a game and I have this problem: the last `if` statement (and all its `else if` statements) are never executed.

Here is the code that doesn’t work:

```js
const compare = prompt("1.mars, 2.jupiter, 3.moon")

if (compare === 2) {
  confirm("your airplane crashed and you died")
} else if (compare === 1) {
  confirm("you arrived safely")
} else if (compare === 3) {
  confirm("you survived an airplane crash but you need to escape")
}
```

Comment: ``prompt`` queries a *string*, but you compare with *integer*s (e.g.: ``'1' === 1`` is equivalent to ``false``)

Comment: you could change your if statements to just use `==` instead of `===`, therefore the type doesn't have to match too: `if (compare == 2)` ... etc

Answer (score 1):

As @Binkan Salaryman very accurately pointed out, prompt is returning a String ('1', '2', etc.).

Either use `==` to compare untyped values like `compare==2` or compare with the correct type: e.g. `compare==='2'`

Comment: `==` and `!=` are almost [never recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/4642212). They’re not always intuitively transitive since they oftentimes unnecessarily perform type coercion. Always use `===` and `!==` instead. Either use `Number(prompt(`…`))` or compare against strings.

Answer (score 0):

use [Equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)( `==` ) instead of Strict equality ( `===` ) operator. With `===`, comparison returns true only if both the operands same in type as well. In your case, the result of prompt returns string, and

```
compareInt === 2; // '2' === 2
```

returns `false` as you are checking for string and number to be same.

```
'2' === 2 returns false as type checking is also done
'2' == 2 returns true as no type checking
```

Comment: _“as no type checking”_ is wrong. `==` and `!=` are almost [never recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/4642212). They’re not always intuitively transitive since they oftentimes unnecessarily perform type coercion. Always use `===` and `!==` instead. Either use `Number(prompt(`…`))` or compare against strings.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little demo. Refactored your code a little. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wsekh3r0/)

The main problem as some people have pointed out is that `prompt` returns a `string` even if you write a `number`.

You'll need to convert this string to an `int` using `parseInt()` function.

```
if(jack === 'yes'){
    var compare = parseInt(prompt("1.mars, 2.jupiter, 3.moon"));
    switch(compare){
        case 2: confirm("your airplane crashed and you died")
            break;
        case 1: confirm("you arrived safely")
            break;
        case 3: confirm("you survived an airplane crash but you need to escape")
            break;
        default:
            confirm("An error occured");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use `parseInt` [_with_ the second parameter, `10`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16880327/4642212). Consider using [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
compareInt = parseInt(compare)
```

Final code looks like:

```
var compare = prompt ("1.mars,2.jupiter,3.moon")
var compareInt = parseInt(compare);
if (compareInt===2) {confirm ("your airplane crashed and you died")}
else if (compareInt===1) {confirm ("you arrived safely")}
else if (compareInt===3){
confirm("you survived an airplane crash but you need to escape")}
```

Answer (score -1):

for work your code you don't need to strict check by **===** you can use the simple comparison with  **==**

- because  **===** will compare both's type also as well as the value
- while **==** only compares the value