# Why am I still getting "false" even after entering right number?

Tags: javascript

Can you find out what's wrong here? Why am I still getting "false" even after entering right number? here is my code..

```js
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var guess = window.prompt('guess the number!');
if (rand === guess)
  console.log('correct');
else
  console.log('false');
console.log(`correct number is : ${rand}`);
```

Comment: `prompt` returns strings, not numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript if statements don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240549/javascript-if-statements-dont-work)

Answer (score 4):

It's because you use the [strict equality operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) which also takes data types into consideration. The `rand` value is a number, but the `guess` value is a string. Therefor the two can never be equal even if the represented value is the same.

```js
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var guess = window.prompt('guess the number!');

console.log(typeof rand);
console.log(typeof guess);
```

You could solve this by using the [equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality)..

```js
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var guess = window.prompt('guess the number!');

if (rand == guess)
  console.log('correct');
else
  console.log('false');
console.log(`correct number is : ${rand}`);
```

..changing the `rand` number to a string..

```js
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var guess = window.prompt('guess the number!');

if (rand.toString() === guess)
  console.log('correct');
else
  console.log('false');
console.log(`correct number is : ${rand}`);
```

..or by changing the `guess` string to a number

```js
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var guess = window.prompt('guess the number!');

if (rand === parseInt(guess, 10))
  console.log('correct');
else
  console.log('false');
console.log(`correct number is : ${rand}`);
```