# Trying to create a JavaScript popup box

Tags: javascript, function

I am supposed to provide messages if the variable entered is higher or lower than a specific number. 
I'm using the if statement to do this, but after the value is entered and the correct message is shown, the second 'if' statement is run too, I don't want this to happen. I've tried using the 'else' statement in place of the second 'if' statement, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var a, name;

name = window.prompt("Please enter your first name", "First Name");

a = window.prompt("Enter a number from 1-100", "1-100");

a = parseInt(a);


myFunction (a, name);

function myFunction(a, name) {
if (a <= 50) {
    alert("Hey your number is less than 50");
}
if (a < 100) {
    alert("Your number is higher than 50")
}
}
</script>
```

Please forgive me as I'm quite new to all of this.

thank you all

Comment: `else if`, not just `else`. Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#Description), please.

Comment: Other things: please use `parseInt(a, 10)`, [not `parseInt(a)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16880327/4642212). Your code specifies _“Enter a number from 1 [to] 100”_, but you _exclude_ 100 by writing `< 100` rather than `<= 100`. _“Hey your number is less than 50”_ is also not true if you check for `<= 50` instead of `< 50`. You’re also not checking for numbers below 1 or non-numeric inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thie `if-else` works perfectly fine for me

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

var a, name;

name = window.prompt("Please enter your first name", "First Name");

a = window.prompt("Enter a number from 1-100", "1-100");

a = parseInt(a);


myFunction (a, name);

function myFunction(a, name) {
    if (a > 0 && a <= 50) {
        alert("Hey your number is less than 50");
    }
    else if(a <= 100){
        alert("Your number is higher than 50")
    }
    else {
         alert("Invalid number");
    }
}
</script>
```

Again, if you look at your if conditions, both are true so it shows both the alerts.

Comment: And again, please use `parseInt(a, 10)`, [not `parseInt(a)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16880327/4642212).

Comment: @user4642212 I think there's no need to use it unless you are working with binary, octa or hexadecimal numbers as  `parseInt(a)` by default parses for decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that even if you put else if after the if statement it will also give a msg since for an example , if 40 <=50 , msg will popup .. and also 40 < 100 is true so the msg also will popup !

correct way :

```
if (a <= 50) {
    alert("Hey your number is less than 50");
}
else if (a<=100) {
    alert("Your number is higher than 50")
}
```

Comment: Here, no need to check a > 50 in the `else if` as it will not go into the second condition if a is less than 50

Comment: @DeepakTerse But here the `a > 0` check is missing, so `a > 50` makes _some_ sense. It would be better to just do `if(Number.isNaN(a)){ return "Invalid number"; } if(a < 1 || a > 100){ return "Number out of range"; } if(a < 50){ return "Number less than 50"; } return "Number at least 50";`, then alert the return value.

Comment: @user4642212 exactly

Comment: @user4642212 make sense