# Issue with behavior in a function - +=

Tags: javascript, function, object, operation

My project involves the user providing a number (in my examples I have been using the number 3000) from an input text box from HTML.  Then in my external js file (which IS declared in the head tag), I have a variable declared as an object with properties.

Essentially an amount is typed within a text box and the button is clicked.  On click it calls the external javascript file, which has an object with properties delared, and a function that begins execution when the button is clicked.

Inside the function, you can see where it pulls the numerical value from the input box from the HTML file, and alters the object properties (and outputs the results to console log).

The head scratcher is that, when it does operator "account.savings -= z;", it works perfectly and produces the desired result of account.savings - 3000 (65247)...but when account.checking +=z; then executes, it mashes the 2 values together instead of adding them (50043000 instead of 8004).

I have tried adding account.checking to just the number 3000 and it works PERFECTLY.

TL:DR - upon function execution, acount.savings -= z; works fine and displays in console log as it should, but acount.savings += z; merges the numbers instead of adding them in console log.

```js
var account = {
  checking: 5004,
  savings: 68247
};

function maths() {

  var z = document.getElementById('amount').value;

  account.savings -= z;
  console.log(account.savings);

  account.checking += z;
  console.log(account.checking);

}
```

```html
Amount <input id="amount" type="number" placeholder="Amount..." class="form-control" step="0.01" name="amount"><br>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="login" onclick="maths()" ;>Transfer</button>
```

Comment: `account.checking += +z;` should be a quick fix; consider checking https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Comment: `+` can be string concatenation, whereas `-` coerces to number

Comment: Another reason JavaScript's inconsistency is gross.

Comment: i want to upvote jonrsharpe's reply.

Answer (score 1):

In javaScript 5004(number) + "3000"(string) equals to "50043000"(string)
You should somehow validate your input and convert it to a number to make sure it's passing the right amount in your function. For example:

```
var account = { checking: 5004, savings: 68247 };
function maths() {
    var z = document.getElementById('amount').value;
    z = parseInt(z);

    account.savings -= z;
    console.log(account.savings);

    account.checking += z;
    console.log(account.checking);
}

maths();
```

Comment: but i dont get how z for account.savings worked as a number (as intended) and for account.checking it became a string.....(the 3000) i fail to see where z changed from a number to a string.

Definitely will try your solution. just wondering why the behavorial change for something i figured would be treated the same.

Comment: it did indeed work but im just wondering why? why was the validation necessary? Again new, but why if it worked for one expression (of the same type) it didn't work for the one after (with no alteration code inbetween)?

Comment: Please use `parseInt` [with the second parameter `10`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16880327/4642212). Consider using [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead, or, specifically for `<input>`s, [`.valueAsNumber`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties).

Comment: @Gr3ghammett javaScript is a loosely typed language. When you add a string number such as "3000" to a real number such as 10, since it's not possible to add a number to a string, it converts the number to string and concats the variables. But, when you use "-" operator, it's not possible to remove a part of string based on another string, so, it converts the string number to a number and then does the operation. That's why "10" + 5 equals to 105 but "10" - 5 equals to 5.

Answer (score 0):

One caveat to [ImanGM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64299060/10156584): if you want to deal with decimals and not just integers, `parseInt` won't work for you. I agree with ImanGM that input validation should be handled, but to answer the question...

String concatenation is being performed instead of addition. This is because `document.getElementById('amount').value` gives us a string. You can circumvent this issue with:

```js
account.checking += Number(z);
```

Comment: but why on account.savings was z being treated as a number correctly, and on account.checking it was being treated as a string?

and yes soon I will be introducing decimals. so Im interested in your input.

Thanks!

Comment: @Gr3ghammett The reason for that is because with `account.savings`, you were using `-=`, which can only be used on numbers, not strings. With `account.checking` you were using `+=`, which is valid for both string concatenation and for addition. As a result, only `-=` resulted in automatic conversion of `z` from a string to a number.