# How function to return a variable?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, return-value, getelementbyid

I want to put number in the data type in html and use button to call the function to return the value to the variable.

```js
function income(sumincome) {
  var sumincome = 0
  sumincome += parseInt(document.getElementById("income").value)
  document.getElementById("resultin").innerHTML = (sumincome)
  return sumincome;
}

function expenses() {
  var sumexpenses = 0
  sumexpenses += parseInt(document.getElementById("expen").value)
  document.getElementById("resultexp").innerHTML = (sumexpenses)
  return sumexpenses;
}

var net = income() - expenses();
```

Comment: The top bit of your JS is missing. The HTML is missing. It really isn't clear what *problem* you are having. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] using the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: Please use `parseInt` [with the second parameter `10`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16880327/4642212). Consider using [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead, or, specifically for `<input>`s, [`.valueAsNumber`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties).

Comment: You always declare a new `sumincome`, set it to `0`, and then add a single value to it. Same thing for `sumexpenses`. It looks like you’re trying to add more than one value, but it’s not clear where the values would be coming from. `var net` is declared outside of any function, so it never changes. If, say, the value of `document.getElementById("income")` changes, do you believe that `net` magically changes with it? Use [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to actually listen for changes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a beginner in javascript. :)

Answer (score 1):

that's very simple :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>

  <script>
    function income(sumincome) {
        var sumincome = 10;
        return sumincome;
    }

    function expenses() {
         var sumexpenses = 5;
         return sumexpenses;
    }

    var net = income() - expenses();
    alert("Value Net : " + net);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```