# Bit of help returning nth character in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I'm having a bit of trouble getting this code to work and would love some advice, basically I'm trying to have user input a message and then amount of skips (n) and have console return the chosen characters.
Here is what I have so far but it's only bringing one back. any advice would be greatly appreciated thanks so much

```
function ShowCharacters(text, n){
  let = parseInt(n);
  let count=0;
  let lastIndex= text.length-1;
  for(let index= 0;index <= lastIndex; index ++ )
     char = text.charAt(n);
      console.log(char)
      count + n;
return char;
}

let inp1 = prompt("Enter message");
let inp2 = prompt( "Enter amount of skips");
ShowCharacters(inp1,inp2);
```

Comment: Please use `parseInt` [_with_ the second parameter, `10`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16880327/4642212). Consider using [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead.

Comment: `count + n;` does nothing. `char = text.charAt(n);` in a loop keeps reassigning and overwriting `char`. Are you aware that `console.log(char)` is outside of your loop?

Comment: (And `count` isn't used anyway.)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: Boss insists on parseInt and I DEFINITELY would rather use parsefloat or Number. It's so frustrating and not my style.

Comment: My code actually returns the first nth integer I just need it to repeat every nth. Not sure what I did to offend so much asking.