# How do i get the accurate total for in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code adds a zero to the start and end of the figure outputted. for example `721` as `07210`.The code below:

```
  let calcData =[];
let total = [];


// initialize calcData
dataKey.map((v) => { 
  calcData[v.name]=0;

  console.log(calcData)
} )
data.map((v) => {
  dataKey.map((col) => { 
    calcData[col.name] += v[col.name];
     total += v[col.name]
     })
```

The Output:

> Harvest: "0423230"
>
> Main__Offertory: "01000"
>
> Second_Offertory: "07820"
>
> Thanks_Giving: "078200"

Comment: v[col.name] may be an string. try like this. let total = 0; (in second line) total+=parseInt(v[col.name]);

Comment: Please use `parseInt` [_with_ the second parameter, `10`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16880327/4642212). Consider using [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead.

Comment: Provide samples for `dataKey` and `data` so that one can infer from them before answering

Answer (score 1):

v[col.name] may be an string. try like this.

```
let calcData =[];
let total = [];


// initialize calcData
dataKey.map((v) => { 
  calcData[v.name]=0;

  console.log(calcData)
} )
data.map((v) => {
  dataKey.map((col) => { 
    calcData[col.name] += v[col.name];
     total += v[col.name]
  })
})
```